# Erlang case returns wrong result

Tags: json, erlang, case

Hi can someone help with my case issue here is a screenshot if u need the UNPACK code just ask ill be happy to post it.

it returns ok as u can see from the screenshot so I don't understand why.

[image: ""]

Comment: The UNPACK code is probably where the problem is. Please do post it.

Comment: sorry ive not got any good at adding code to comments so heres another pic :)
http://i.imgur.com/k51ZgPF.png

Comment: parse returns fine in my case my first cmd does not have a room so it returns {1, undefined, <<"Dave">>}
i also forgot to say this code works in another websocket server but the server it works on has a problem returning large data so im switching to cowboy as that works perfect :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is `jsonMsg`

A bareword starting with a lower-case character in Erlang creates an atom (effectively an enumeration), causing your match specification to fail.

Change `jsonMsg` to `JsonMsg`

Comment: cheers for that i don't think it was even that as im not a complete noob and fixed that before you even replied, i have another question but not sure if its possible or not i have a php function that encodes a string i also have the reverse code also, do you think the reverse code could be done in erlang i would post the code but its kindy custom and in years to come i don't want someone using it to gain access to certain aspects of my erlang app and or site but i can tell u what functions are called. do you think i should ask another question or just go it alone. Tnx

Comment: Anything you can do with PHP you can do with Erlang. It will probably look quite a bit different in the Erlang version, but I promise you there is a way to do it. Go it alone for the time being; if you find yourself absolutely stumped then ask a question. If worse comes to worse, you can always implement it as an Erlang NIF. Be patient, though; functional programming is very different from imperative programming, but those differences can be very useful once you master them.

Comment: Ok thanks for that yea ive noticed u should see how fast this websocket chat is never have i seen anything so fast i even added html5 drag and drop for images then there sent over the wire instantly i mean each image is like 180000 chars its insane :). Thanks for your help on this issue ill prob attempt the php thing in few days as long as i know its possible that does me fine :)